# Function to return a unique array from a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to declare a Selection in memory to a variable 'rRange' and I would like to remove duplicates and transform to an array.

I have tried the following:

```
Function getArray()
  Dim rRange As Range
  Dim newRange As Range
  Dim resultArray() As Variant

  Set rRange = Selection
  newRange = rRange.RemoveDuplicates

  getArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(newRange)
End Function
```

But I am getting a 'Type Mismatch' error on the .RemoveDuplicates section, I have been playing around for the past few hours at this and just cannot get it right...advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RemoveDuplicates` does not return a value. You will need to recalculate the extent of your range after calling that method.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, how do I recalculate it?  Bearing in mind I don't want to actually affect the spreadsheet I am reading the data from.

Comment: Without modifying the worksheet, you have fewer options. Two options are: 1) Create a new worksheet, and copy the range to the new worksheet. Call `RemoveDuplicates` on the copied range, copy that range to an in-memory array, and then delete the new worksheet. 2) Copy the range to an in-memory array and write your own `RemoveDuplicates` method. Unfortunately, `RemoveDuplicates` is a member of the `Range` class, and `Range` objects are always stored in worksheets.

Comment: I realised the issue and went with option 1, thanks!